# ActionChains not performing F5 pressing using Firefox

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

This has been bugging me for a long time, if anyone can help me spot the mistake in my program, it will be appreciated.

Thanks.

```
class amz_bot():
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def login(self):
        self.driver.get("http://www.amazon.com/")
        time.sleep(5)
        while True:
            ActionChains(self.driver).send_keys(Keys.F5).perform()            
            time.sleep(5)
bot = amz_bot()
bot.login()
```

Comment: The F5 is never pressed. I tried chromium as well. Nada

Comment: Hi Bob. I can't comment on the f5 key but Are you just trying to refresh the page? If so you can do driver.Refresh

Comment: The refresh method works. However the website im scrapping needs me to be active otherwise kick me out at 20min mark. I'm not sure why the button clickings doesn't count as activities! Thus I am trying to see if refreshing would make it seem like there are actions going on. however the driver.refresh is not considered as activities to this website as well. I am scratching my head off....

Comment: The F5 might not work because it's a low level keyboard action against "nothing" -  I'm just looking at some code at the moment but if you get selenium to interact with the page before pressing f5 that might be enough... I'll let you know either way when i've run some stuff :-)

Comment: Thanks for your input and let me know the outcome plz!!!

Comment: i feel your pain that it's frustrating that it doesn't work.Can't see why it wouldn't - i'm not as sure about the active context anymore either... but... There are a few alternatives i've outlined below that might work. Have a look and let me know if you need any more support

Comment: i tried the same thing in c# and i get the same result as you. It's not just you so you'll probably want to consider one of the workarounds in the answer below

Comment: Yup! I’ll have to stay with the driver.refresh() method for now. On a side note, this website I’m on is really one of a kind. No matter what I do, I’m automatically logged out at the 20min mark. So I Guess really no way around that....SMH

Comment: If the below is useful for you be sure to make it as the right answer. Helps others in the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the F5 isn't going anywhere.

Selenium spins up a browser but the `ActionChain` object is a low level key press. Even though it's created with the driver object, it doesn't have the context of the window.

If you were to send any other (normal) keys - where are they sent?

One solution is to use `send_keys_to_element` instead just blind `send_keys`.
This will put the focus in the window then send f5.

In my solution here, i'm assuming it only has one `html` tag... It's a fair assumption, but, my first attempt used `body` and then it turned out there were 3 pf those.

So... Try this:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

class amz_bot():
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    def login(self):
        self.driver.get("http://www.amazon.com/")
        time.sleep(5)
        while True:
            e = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'html')))
            ActionChains(self.driver).send_keys_to_element(e, Keys.F5).perform()
            time.sleep(10)
            


bot = amz_bot()
bot.login()
```

This kind of worked for me - but it's weird. When selenium presses F5 (so it's doing the key press!) the page isn't refreshing, it's going into a search result.

I'm going to have another look in a moment (and i'll update the answer) but this is a step in the right direction. At least something is happening with the key press.

---

Update - Another option is to use javascript. Instead of F5, this refreshes the page:

```
self.driver.execute_script("location.reload()")
```

It's worth a try for it's simplicity but it might be similar to the standard `browser.refresh()`

---

Another update:

Another approach is to navigate the browser to the current url - doing the same job as the refresh

```py
self.driver.get(self.driver.current_url)
```